# codigo en sql no cumple la condicion AND

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

donde está comentado me imprime por ejemplo una fecha
donde en prestamo el dia tiene un 06, pero en la fecha devolucion no lo tiene y me esta excluyendo igual ese registro, siendo que yo le puse un AND para que cuando en devolucion sea diferente de 06 y en prestamo sea diferente de 06 ahi lo excluya :S

```
--no funciona LA CONDICION COMENTADA
SELECT e.ID_LECTOR,e.NOMBRE, p.FECHA_PRESTAMO, p.FECHA_DEVOLUCION
FROM ESTUDIANTE e
JOIN PRESTAMO p
ON e.ID_LECTOR = p.ID_LECTOR
GROUP BY e.ID_LECTOR,e.NOMBRE, p.FECHA_PRESTAMO, p.FECHA_DEVOLUCION
--HAVING ((EXTRACT(DAY FROM  p.FECHA_PRESTAMO) <> 06)
--AND (EXTRACT(DAY FROM  p.FECHA_DEVOLUCION) <> 06))
ORDER BY ID_LECTOR;
```

en pocas palabras quiero que si el dia en fecha_prestamo es 6 y el dia en fecha devolucion es 6 no muestre ese registro, pero no lo esta haciendo en la condicion comentada

Comment: Me parece que debes usar `WHERE` en lugar de `HAVING`

Comment: pero no puedo utilizar un where si uso el group by...

Comment: porque dices que no puedes usar where?

Comment: tenia entendido que no porque por eso se creo el having para cunado se usa group by, pero al parecer se puede de todos modos no funciona porque lo borra igual... :/